# Protecting controller actions and routes in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, acl, symfony2-voter

Official documentation on Symfony pages suggest using ROLE_ADMIN (example) attribute in the ACL call

```
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');
```

my question is if it is possible to use ACL call without the ROLE_ prefix.

The issue is that we have multiple systems without ROLES but with permissions as "USER.CREATE" or "USER_CREATE" which would protect the route POST /user/create and action Create() in UserController.

The best solution would be to have a Voter which would call the ACL as

```
$objectName = 'USER';
$action = 'CREATE';
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($objectName. '_'. $action, null, 'Unable to access this page!');
```

But this does not work because everything relays on ROLE_ prefix. 
Did anyone tried to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, ROLE is mandatory prefix in symfony role voter and I do not think it can be avoided (it is hardcoded) but you can create your own voters and add logic you need there, you can read more here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Also a great tutoral for voters:

https://stovepipe.systems/post/symfony-security-roles-vs-voters

Comment: The issue with custom voter and that kind of checking is that it can't be used with ACL as in your links 
$AuthorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') 
is used and in custom voters we can't have something like 
$AuthorizationChecker->isGranted('USER_CREATE') 

Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: isGranted('ROLE_' . 'USER_CREATE') I think I remember reading somewhere that the ROLE_ prefix might be going away in S4.

Comment: @SuperManSl  But in your custom voter you can check if user has a role, you dont have to do is granted? If I understood you correctly you are saving that kind of permissions in db, so just do in_Array or something inside of your custom voter.